# Adding background scripts to a firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to add a file(background.js) which is a background script for my firefox extension.
I added content scripts to my main.js using the following code.

```
 var panel = panels.Panel({
   contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
   onHide: handleHide,
   contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("js/jquery.js"), 
                  self.data.url("tipsy/jquery.tipsy.js"),,
                  self.data.url("js/settings.js")]
});
```

How do I add background scripts to the main.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the file in the `lib` folder.

> Except for scripts that interact directly with web content, all the JavaScript code you'll write or use when developing add-ons using the SDK is part of a CommonJS module.

Essentially, backend script don't share variables like content scripts/normal JS. You `export` and `require` variables between modules.

See [adding local modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK#Local_Modules)